# No data insertion in the database in django when form is been submited

Tags: python, django, database, model

I am trying to create a registration form using Django as I have created the form and model on the website after clicking the submit it calls for the view as action provided to the form but it seems that no data is been inserted in the database and no error in the terminal as well. I have tried to find solutions but none of them worked. I am new in the field of python and web development.
below is the code that I have used on the website.

model.py

```
from django.db import models


class Writer(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
   contactnumber = models.IntegerField()
   gender = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=254)
   date = models.DateField()
   class Meta:
       db_table = 'Writers'
```

below code are of my views.py

views.py

```
def createuser(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    first_name = request.POST.get('firstname')
    last_name = request.POST.get('lastname')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    contactnumber = request.POST.get('phonenumber')
    gender = request.POST.get('gender')
    password = contactnumber
    
    if username == None or first_name == None or last_name == None or email == None or contactnumber == None or gender == None:      
        return render(request,"adminpanal/userregister.html",{'alert_flag': True})
    else:
        createnewuser = Writer(username=username,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,email=email,gender=gender,contactnumber=contactnumber,password=password,date=datetime.today())
        createnewuser.save()
        
        return redirect('/Blogdashboard/dashboard')
   return HttpResponse("Doen,user created")
```

below are the Html form that I have used

```
 <form action="/Blogdashboard/createuser" method="post" style="margin: 5px">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div >
                    <label class="labelinput">Username</label>
                    <input name = "username" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" required>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <label class="labelinput">First name</label>
                    <input name = "firstname" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" required>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <label class="labelinput">Last name</label>
                    <input name = "lastname" type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" required>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <label class="labelinput">Email id</label>
                    <input name = "email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <label class="labelinput">Contact number</label>
                    <input name = "phonenumber" type="phone" class="form-control" id="phonenumber" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="labelinput">Gender</label>
                    <select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-select " aria-label="Default select example" required>
                        <option selected>select</option>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        <option value="Transgender">Transgender</option>
                      </select>
                </div>
                
                <center>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 20px;" >New writer </button>
                </center>
                {% if alert %}
                <script>alert("Please enter Your details blank feild are not allowed.")</script>  
                {% endif %}
            </form>
```

As I have checked my terminal as well as my website live view it works fine all the data from the form are been received at the create user view and after submitting the form as I am been redirected to the dashboard as I have returned it, but no data is been inserted in the database as I have seen the terminal too there is no error on it.

Comment: please attach your urls.py

Comment: also use auto_now_add=True in your datefield

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
createnewuser=Writer.objects.create_user(username,first_name,last_name,email,gender,contactnumber,password)
createnewuser.save()
```

You should use the default 'User' model of django.It will be easy for you

Answer (score 0):

Question, why are you not using a ModelForm?
A modelform can do a lot of validation for you, such as checking for required fields and even custom validators?

See documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/